# override javascript from module

Tags: magento2, javascript

I want to override file from module.
`vendor/mageworx/module-storelocator/view/frontend/web/js/locations-modal.js`

I create file
`app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_child/MageWorx_StoreLocator/web/js/locations-modal.js`

That wont work for me so i add file
`app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_child/MageWorx_StoreLocator/web/js/requirejs-config.js`

```
    map: {
        '*': {
            'locations-modal': 'js/locations-modal.js',
        }
    }
};
```

I try move require-config.js in serveral locations still not working.

orginal requirejs config
`vendor/mageworx/module-storelocator/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
    map: {
        '*': {
            'locations-modal': 'MageWorx_StoreLocator/js/locations-modal',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***requirejs-config.js** no need to override this but still if you want override path should be this*

```
app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_child/MageWorx_StoreLocator/requirejs-config.js

map: {
        '*': {
            'locations-modal': 'MageWorx_StoreLocator/js/locations-modal',
    }
    }
```

***Just Need to upgrade/deploy and check***

Comment: this is not working i did c:c c:f static content deploy.

Comment: Did You Do Upgrade?

Comment: No, don`t think so. Any additional command ?

Comment: This is required command 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade,php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f after check

Comment: Worked. It seams i did that config You say before(had different history configs) just not to give setup:upgrade thx